# Найдите все блюда, которые отмечены как вегетарианские (Vegetarian), но в ингредиентах содержится мясо индейки (Turkey). Вывести: Name

Tags: mysql, sql

SELECT Name
FROM dishes
WHERE name LIKE 'Turkey_%'
мой способ решение

Запрос составлен верно
#сайт принимает
#но выдает ошибку снизу!
Число возвращенных строк разное. Количество: 1. Ожидается: 0

Comment: *Запрос составлен верно* Нет. Где проверка на веганство?

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что должна быт таблица блюд, и должна быть таблица ингредиентов, а еще таблица связей между  ними.